# Ajax code not working in IE.But Fine in all other browsers

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [script not working in Ajax returned value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14117694/script-not-working-in-ajax-returned-value)

I am using ajax for fetching some data.There is a link "Show items of this user".while cliking on it it will call a function 'callfunc' with parameter 'userid'.This ajax function will go to getdetails.php and and will fetch some details of that corresponding user.

```
<tr><td colspan="6" align="right"><a href="javascript:callfunc(<?= $row5[user_id]; ?>)" style="font-size:10px;">Show items of this user</a></td></tr>


<script type="text/javascript">
function callfunc(str)
{

//alert(str);
if (str.length==0)
{ 
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="";
return;
}
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","getdetails.php?cid="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

getdetails.php

```
<?php
require 'include/connect.php';
$cid=$_GET['cid'];
$sql="select * from table where status='Active' and user_id=$cid";
$res=mysql_query($sql); 
$tot=mysql_num_rows($res);
if($tot>0){
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
echo '<tr class="detail9txt" height="30"> 
      <td width="2%"><input type="checkbox" name="item" id="item" value="'.$row[item_id].'"></td>
      <td align="center" width="12%" style="vertical-align:baseline;">
        <a href="detail.php?item_id='.$row[item_id].'" id="link3">'.$row['title'].'</a>
      </td> 
<td align="center" width="17%" style="vertical-align:baseline;">
'.substr($row['des'], 0, 20).'
</td></tr>';
}
?>
```

This code is working properly in mozilla,chrome,and opera.But not working in IE.While clicking on the link "Show Items of this user" nothing happens in IE.Any idea?

Comment: You should start using a javascript library like **jQuery**

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14110189/1723893). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Are you a bot @NullPointer? Every time someone uses ext:mysql you are copy-pasta...

Comment: Microsoft failed to properly implement XMLHttpRequest in IE7. `XHR` can't require local files properly. You should use `ActiveX` object in `IE` even if `XHR` is available

Comment: The exact same ajax code works fine here: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first . Maybe an issue with your html? You are not showing what "result" looks like.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl: https://gist.github.com/3881905 More details on the [**PHP Chat**](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`Jquery ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). It supports just about every browser. Please be mindful that the next release of Jquery, version 1.9, will be [dropping support](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/06/28/jquery-core-version-1-9-and-beyond/) for all IE browsers before ie9.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "getdetails.php",
  data: { cid : str }
}).done(function(response) {
  $('#result').text() = response;
});
```

Comment: Not an answer. Can be a comment! And dont know who is give up vote to such answers!

Comment: Please don't get butthurt.

Comment: I tried <script type="text/javascript">
function callfunc(str)
{

$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "getdetails.php",
  data: { cid : str }
}).done(function(response) {
  $('#result').text() = response;
});

}</script>But nothing happens while clicking on the link "show items of this member"

Comment: Ensure that you have the following script reference in your document head and that it comes before all other libraries: `<script rel=javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>`

Comment: Not helpful to explain the issue. And jQuery 1.9 will support IE 6/7/8 (cf. the link in your reply).

Answer (score -1):

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function callfunc(str)
    {
    try{
    var ox = ((window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"));
            if (ox) {
                ox.open("GET", "getdetails.php?cid="+str);
                ox.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
                ox.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
                ox.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (ox.readyState == 4) {
                        if (ox.status == 200) {
                            eval(callback_function + "('" + escape(ox.responseText) + "')");
                        } else {
                           alert(ox.readyState);
                           alert(ox.stauts);
                        }
                    }
                }
                ox.send(null);
            }
    }catch(e){
    alert(e.Message);
    }

    }

</script>
```

Try this code atleast it will provide you status or any error in ie browser....

Comment: Nothing happens and nothing alerts